# drop_duplicates - ValueError: keep must be either "first", "last" or False

Tags: python, debugging, pandas, duplicates

I have installed Pandas 17.0.  I am now getting a strange error

`ValueError: keep must be either "first", "last" or False`

when I attempt this:

```
ids=ids.drop_duplicates('ID')
```

This always worked in previous Pandas versions, the code has not changed.  BTW `ids` is a dataframe containing a column of integers...

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-34-6e98a890591b>", line 1, in <module>
     ids=ids.drop_duplicates('ID')

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\decorators.py",
 line 89, in wrapper
     return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line
 1164, in drop_duplicates
     return super(Series, self).drop_duplicates(keep=keep, inplace=inplace)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\decorators.py",
 line 89, in wrapper
     return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 576,
 in drop_duplicates
     duplicated = self.duplicated(keep=keep)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\decorators.py",
 line 89, in wrapper
     return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line
 1169, in duplicated
     return super(Series, self).duplicated(keep=keep)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\decorators.py",
 line 89, in wrapper
     return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 603,
 in duplicated
     duplicated = lib.duplicated(keys, keep=keep)

File "pandas\lib.pyx", line 1383, in pandas.lib.duplicated
 (pandas\lib.c:24490)

ValueError: keep must be either "first", "last" or False
```

Note the `keep=keep`?  The default in Pandas 17.0 for `drop_duplicates` is `keep='first'`.  So if I don't specify shouldn't it default to that?  And why would I get an error here?  Bug in Pandas 17.0?

Comment: Your traceback indicates that `ids` is a `Series` what does `type(ids)` show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error indicates that `ids` is in fact a `Series` for which the first param is the [`keep`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) param, if `ids` really is a df then this error would not happen as [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) first param is `subset`.

Comment: Wow that was quick.  Thanks Ed.  I'm embarrassed I missed this.  Did something change in 17 that would have prompted this error?  My mistake that this was a series.  Much appreciated...  I'll accept the answer in 10 minutes when they let me!

Comment: This was added in [`0.17.0`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#other-enhancements) scroll a bit further down for the bit on `drop_duplicates`

Answer (score 1):

I tried the syntax (using `keep`), previously was `take_last`...

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': ['cat'] * 3 + ['dog'] * 4,
                   'c2': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]})

print(df)
print(df.drop_duplicates())   
print(df.drop_duplicates(['c1', 'c2'],keep='first'))   
print(df.drop_duplicates(['c1', 'c2'],keep='last'))   
print(df.drop_duplicates(['c1', 'c2'],keep=False))   #drops all but one cat stays
```

By default for `drop_duplicates()` it's `keep='first'` and all columns accounted.